# Mi base de datos me está arrojando error al crear una nueva tabla en MySql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

Resulta que hice una redefinición de mi base de datos que lleva las calificaciones de alumnos en la universidad y agregué dos tablas nuevas: la tabla **Matricula** que se encarga de asociar la carrera que estudia un alumno y **ProgramacionPeriodo**, la cual uso para establecer cuáles asignaturas de una materia se tendrán para un semestre con sus respectivas secciones.

Ahora bien, necesito crear una tabla que consolide la información de Matricula y ProgramacionPeriodo que deseo denominar Expediente, en la cual aparte de mezclar la información de dichas tablas, me permita almacenar la nota del estudiante y asociar también otra tabla llamada TipoNota, dado que debo seleccionar si la nota definitiva se obtuvo en examen final, de reparación o cualquier otro tipo que defina el usuario.

Cuando trato de hacer el enlace en cuestión, me arroja este error:

> Executing SQL script in server ERROR: Error 1822: Failed to add the
>   foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint
>   'fk_ExpedienteAlumno_Matricula1' in the referenced table 'matricula'

```
SQL Code:
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `EjercicioBI`.`ExpedienteAlumno`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `EjercicioBI`.`ExpedienteAlumno` (
          `Matricula_CedulaEstudiante` INT(8) NOT NULL,
          `Matricula_idCarrera` INT(4) NOT NULL,
          `idAsignatura` INT(4) NOT NULL,
          `idSeccion` INT(2) NOT NULL,
           `idPeriodo` INT(4) NOT NULL,
           `idTipoNota` INT(2) NOT NULL,
          INDEX `fk_ExpedienteAlumno_Matricula1_idx` (`Matricula_CedulaEstudiante` ASC, `Matricula_idCarrera` ASC) VISIBLE,
           PRIMARY KEY (`Matricula_CedulaEstudiante`, `Matricula_idCarrera`, `idAsignatura`, `idSeccion`, `idPeriodo`),
           INDEX `fk_ExpedienteAlumno_ProgramacionPeriodo1_idx` (`idAsignatura` ASC, `idSeccion` ASC, `idPeriodo` ASC) VISIBLE,
           INDEX `fk_ExpedienteAlumno_TipoNota1_idx` (`idTipoNota` ASC) VISIBLE,
           CONSTRAINT `fk_ExpedienteAlumno_Matricula1`
             FOREIGN KEY (`Matricula_CedulaEstudiante` , `Matricula_idCarrera`)
             REFERENCES `EjercicioBI`.`Matricula` (`CedulaEstudiante` , `idCarrera`)
             ON DELETE NO ACTION
             ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
           CONSTRAINT `fk_ExpedienteAlumno_ProgramacionPeriodo1`
             FOREIGN KEY (`idAsignatura` , `idSeccion` , `idPeriodo`)
             REFERENCES `EjercicioBI`.`ProgramacionPeriodo` (`idAsignatura` , `idSeccion` , `idPeriodo`)
             ON DELETE NO ACTION
             ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
           CONSTRAINT `fk_ExpedienteAlumno_TipoNota1`
             FOREIGN KEY (`idTipoNota`)
             REFERENCES `EjercicioBI`.`TipoNota` (`idTipoNota`)
             ON DELETE NO ACTION
             ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
         ENGINE = InnoDB
```

> SQL script execution finished: statements: 15 succeeded, 1 failed
>   Fetching back view definitions in final form. Nothing to fetch

Les muestro el modelo que llevo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo lo que coloqué en las tablas Matricula, ProgramacionPeriodo y Expediente lo defini como PK para que no se repitieran los datos que introduzca allí.

Dejo acá en un archivo TXT el log que me arroja Workbench al momento de actualizar los cambios para que puedan indicarme el error que estoy cometiendo y  el cual estoy desconociendo... [Este es el enlace](http://filesharing24.com/d/BzW)

Comment: Puede que no estén declaradas en la base de datos

Comment: Si están declaradas en la base de datos. De hecho allí coloqué como adjunto el archivo TXT donde se ve que si están esas tablas.

Comment: El error es claro: *`Missing index for constraint 'fk_ExpedienteAlumno_Matricula1' in the referenced table 'matricula'`*. Significa que **las columnas `CedulaEstudiante`  e `idCarrera` no forman parte de un índice en la tabla `matricula`**. Las columnas no indexadas no pueden ser usadas como referencias de llave foránea. Lo lógico sería que `CedulaEstudiante`  e `idCarrera` sean la llave primaria de `matricula` o que constituyan un índice único en ella. ¿Serías tan amable de mostrar lo que arroja un `SHOW CREATE TABLE matricula;`?